# How can I layer my Google Fusion Table with Google API code?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am trying to layer my fusion table over a Google elevation map. I know my fusion table's ID but it doesn't seem to load when I open the html file. I've tried to place the fusion table layer in other parts of the code but that just seemed to screw up the whole thing.
At the moment, only the elevation map is loading.

Thanks for the help!

So far my code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Southern Ontario Ski Resort Elevation Map</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>

var elevator;
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var toronto = new google.maps.LatLng(43.653226, -79.383184);


layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: '\'Latitude\'',
      from: '1vYUBXl1TCBYOjuz9hH97rFPmtoVniB2-ytxqmlk'
    }
  });
  layer.setMap(map);

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: toronto,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', getElevation);
}

function getElevation(event) {

  var locations = [];

  var clickedLocation = event.latLng;
  locations.push(clickedLocation);

  var positionalRequest = {
    'locations': locations
  }

  elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {

      if (results[0]) {

       infowindow.setContent('The elevation at this point <br>is ' + results[0].elevation + ' meters.');
        infowindow.setPosition(clickedLocation);
        infowindow.open(map);
      } else {
        alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Elevation service failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load your Fusion Table before you've created the map.  This seems to work now:

```
//...
function initialize() {
var elevator;
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var toronto = new google.maps.LatLng(43.653226, -79.383184);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: toronto,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: '\'Latitude\'',
      from: '1vYUBXl1TCBYOjuz9hH97rFPmtoVniB2-ytxqmlk'
    }
  });
  layer.setMap(map);

  elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();//...
```